# ZIP file with Unicode file names fails to unzip on MIUI phone

Tags: windows, zip, unzip, windows-explorer, miui

I have a ZIP file zipping up a lot of files with extreme Unicode filenames.

Zipping and unzipping it using Windows explorer is no problem, and copying a directory containing the files to the MIUI phone is also no problem.

But when I copy the ZIP file to the MIUI phonoe, then unzip it using the phone's unzipper, it fails to unzip.

Is it reasonable to assume that the phone's unzipper just cannot handle the extremity?